# JQUERY Draggable/Droppable images: How to create save functions for User

Tags: javascript, save, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a basic offline HTML/CSS/JQuery draggable/droppable functions.
Please see attached image:
[webpage design with save new placemen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxZ1w.jpg)
Now I want to create a save new placement button for users, so that the new image placement gets saved into the html/CSS...and by next start of the webpage the last image placement is shown.

I'm a newbie and I am interested in getting a direction / keywords how to manage that.

Thanks in million for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are maybe what are you looking for. When you click on the save button, call a function who save a serialized array containing ids and positions of the tiles in a cookie. Then you can recover data by reading this cookie.

Another way is to save data in a database by using an AJAX call.